# Web Deployment Tool does not work from localhost, but works from remote

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008-r2, web-deployment, webdeploy

Setup:

1. Windows server 2008 R2
2. Web Deployment Tool 2.1 installed and running
3. Management Service installed and running

I can deploy from my development machine using VS 2010 or msbuild, when specify the remote url to be "mydeploymentserver"

When I type in the browser of my development machine `http://localhost/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE` it asks for basic auth, and when I provide the user and pass, it displays a blank page (I assume that the auth passes, as it does not ask again).

The weird problem is, that when I run msbuild task on the server itself, using remote url "localhost", it reports this error:

```
Remote agent (URL http://localhost/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE) could not be contacted. Make sure the remote agent service is installed and started on the target computer.

An unsupported response was received. The response header 'MSDeploy.Response' was '' but 'v1' was expected.

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

Also, if I start the browser on the deployment server itself, and hit the url `http://localhost/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE` it reports Internal Server Error 500 without any other information. Note - it does not ask for username/password like it does when I try the url from another machine.

Another weird thing is, that there are no log files for the management service in C:\inetpub\logs\wmsvc, even if the logging is enabled and the service is started.

Any idea what can be wrong? Why it should work from outside, but not for localhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Web Deployment Tool seems to have problems with "localhost". This is a common problem. It is probably some security thing from Microsoft.  Use the full name (FQDN) of the server instead of localhost.